# Improving performance of Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-kafka

We're running on apache kafka 0.10.0.x and spring 3.x and cannot use spring kafka as it is supported with spring framework version 4.x.

Therefore, we are using the native Kafka Producer API to produce messages.

Now the concern that i have is the performance of my producer. The thing is i believe a call to `producer.send` is what really makes the connection to the Kafka broker and then puts the message onto the buffer and then attempts to send and then possibly calls your the provided callback method in the `producer.send()`.

Now the KafkaProducer documentation says that it uses a buffer and another I/O thread to perform the send and that they should be closed appropriately so that there is no leakage of resources.

From what i understand, this means that if i have 100s of messages being sent every time i invoke `producer.send()` it attempts to connect to the broker which is an expensive I/O operation.

Can you please correct my understanding if i am wrong or maybe suggest a better to use the KafkaProducer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is partially right.

As @leshkin pointed out there are configuration parameters to tune how the *KafkaProducer* will handle buffering of messages to be sent.

However independently from the buffering strategy, the producer will take care of caching established connections to topic-leader brokers.

Indeed you can tune for how long the producer will keep such connection around using the `connections.max.idle.ms` parameter (defaults to 9 minutes).

So to respond to your original question, the I/O cost of establishing a connection to the broker happens only on the first `send` invocation and will be amortised over time as long as you have data to send.

Comment: Ok - This helps, i can tweak the properties and use them appropriately. Is there a recommended approach to use this with spring? I mean i was thinking of creating the KafkaProducer as a singleton bean and then inject it wherever required, but in this case will there be a leakage of resources or performance implications?

Comment: Well the reccomendeed way to use KafkaProducer is to have a single instance and share it between threads. So actually what you're planning to do seems to be ok. At least that is how I would do it years ago when I still was using Spring. No idea if in the meantime the Spring idiomatic way of doing something like this has changed. By the way, if you think the answer is satisfactory, please accept it.

Answer (score 10):

The two important configuration parameters of kafka producer are 'batch.size' and 'linger.ms'. So you basically have a choice: you can wait until the producer batch is full, or the producer time out.

- batch.size – This is an upper limit of how many messages Kafka Producer will attempt to batch before sending – specified in bytes.
- linger.ms – How long will the producer wait before sending in order to allow more messages to get accumulated in the same batch.

It depends on your use case, but I would suggest to take a closer look on these parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In the below conditions you need to configure batch.size,  linger.ms &   compression.type properties in your kafka prodocer to increase the performance.

1) If records are arriving faster than the kafka producer can send.

2) If you have huge amount of data in the your respective Topic, its really burden to your kafka producer.

3) if you have a bottlenecks

```
batch.size = 16_384 * 4
 linger.ms 200
compression.type = "snappy"

props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16_384 * 4);
    // Send with little bit buffering
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 200);    
  //Use Snappy compression for batch compression.
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
```

[kafka Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-kafka-performance-tuning)

[Performance tunning](https://de.slideshare.net/JiangjieQin/producer-performance-tuning-for-apache-kafka-63147600)

[Kafka Perforamnce tunning](https://data-flair.training/blogs/kafka-performance-tuning/)