# Kafka producer batch.size doesn't take effect

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka 1.0, I increased the batch.size=100K for optimizing my producer performance. But I found there is no any effect whatever I set batch.size=100K or 1000K or just 1K. Also, I set my linger.ms=5, but it made the performance even worse.
When I debug the source code of Kafka producer as following：

```
if (result.batchIsFull || result.newBatchCreated) {
     this.sender.wakeup();
}
```

I found the value of result.newBatchCreated always true, I guess that's why the batch.size didn't take any effect, because it wakeup the sender each time not when batchIsFull=true.

I'm so confused now, any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of this one: [Improving performance of Kafka Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600395/improving-performance-of-kafka-producer/45611913#45611913)

But in a nutshell, the `batch.size` and the `linger.ms` parameters should be tuned together because there is a trade-off:

> In your example, the producer will send the current batch to server if the current batch is full (this value is in **bytes**, so 100 bytes what IMO is to little) *OR* the linger timeout happened.

So if you have to experiment and tune with these parameters in order to find the optimal settings.

Comment: hi, the batch.size was 100000, I just modified the question. When I set linger.ms = 10, whatever batch.size I set, it always same slow.

Comment: Yes, because your batch only fills up for 10ms. You need to set it so that your batch has time to fill up. However long it takes to accumulate 1000k records or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, I know now, it's because I was using sync API, not Async.

Comment: There is no sync Producer. To block on produce you need to call get() on the Future returned from the async API as in “producer.send(record).get()”. Either way this should not change the underlying kafka protocol fetch requests which is what is commonly meant as “batching” and which is controlled by linger.ms.