# Kafka producer optimization

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have a huge bulk of data record to produce for Kafka using batching and compression.

I have tried many properties of the producer to fix the exception/timeout while sending the data to the broker.

```
My one record size is 5486 Bytes(total count is around 20000).
```

Below is my properties

```
acks=all
retries=0
batch.size=1MB
buffer.memory=101*1024*1024
linger.ms=1000
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
compression.type=lz4
request.timeout.ms=90000
props.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_FETCH_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, 90000);
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 90000
```

definitely increasing timeout and other large value will affect the throughput of my producer.

I question is which one is good.
1. optimizing the batch.size, other timeouts by increasing them.
2. Using retry count + optimal value of timeout properties.

Exceptions

```
1)2018-05-29 09:19:40.919 ERROR 134700 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload=' 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for demoTopicxyz-0 due to 30012 ms has passed since last append
```

Comment: Could u post the exception u are getting?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600395/improving-performance-of-kafka-producer/45611913#45611913